# How to combine AutoDataAttribute with InlineData

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, autofixture

I heavily use the Autofixture AutoData Theories for creating my data and mocks. However this prevents me from using the InlineData Attributes from XUnit to pipe in a bunch of different data for my tests.

So I am basically looking for something like this:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqDataAttribute]
[InlineData(3,4)]
[InlineData(33,44)]
[InlineData(13,14)]
public void SomeUnitTest([Frozen]Mock<ISomeInterface> theInterface,  MySut sut, int DataFrom, int OtherData)
{
     // actual test omitted
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: See also [AutoFixture, xUnit.net, and Auto Mocking](http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/31/autofixture-xunit-net-and-auto-mocking/).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You'll have to create your own `InlineAutoMoqDataAttribute`, similar to this:

```
public class InlineAutoMoqDataAttribute : InlineAutoDataAttribute
{
    public InlineAutoMoqDataAttribute(params object[] objects) : base(new AutoMoqDataAttribute(), objects) { }
}
```

and you'd use it like this:

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoMoqData(3,4)]
[InlineAutoMoqData(33,44)]
[InlineAutoMoqData(13,14)]
public void SomeUnitTest(int DataFrom, int OtherData, [Frozen]Mock<ISomeInterface> theInterface, MySut sut)
{
     // actual test omitted
}
```

Note that the inlined data, the ints in this case, must be the first parameters of the test method.
All the other parameters will be provided by `AutoFixture`.

Comment: See also http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2011/08/25/combining-data-theories-in-autofixture-xunit-extension/

Comment: I got an exception when utilizing the above snippet. The following, instead, seems to be up to date with current Nunit features:
`public InlineAutoMoqDataAttribute(params object[] objects) : base(() => new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()), objects)`

Comment: The answer is a bit outdated, since there is no class `AutoMoqDataAttribute` anymore. Up to date version is:
`public InlineAutoMoqDataAttribute(params object[] objects) : base(new AutoDataAttribute(), objects) { }`.
So, instead of `AutoMoqDataAttribute` `AutoDataAttribute` should be used.

Answer (score 7):

With the latest AutoFixture, you can use [Inline AutoData Theories](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#inline-autodata-theories)

> Uses the InlineData values for the the first method arguments, and then uses AutoData for the rest (when the InlineData values run out).